# Accessing UserControl's DataContext from another UserControl

Tags: c#, silverlight

Given these classes:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       //...

    }
}
public partial class LoginForm : StackPanel
{
   private LoginRegistrationWindow parentWindow;
   private LoginInfo loginInfo = new LoginInfo();
   public LoginForm()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       //...
   }

   private void LoginOperation_Completed(LoginOperation loginOperation)
   {

    if (loginOperation.LoginSuccess)
    {
            // Here I need to access MainPages's DataContext property and set it with my ViewModel
    }
   }
}
```

I want to set `MainPage`'s DataContext property inside `LoginFrom`. So I created the static instance of the `MainPage` class in the class itself:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public static MainPage Instance { get; private set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Instance = this;
    }
}
```

Now I can access to the `MainPage`'s DataContext this way:

```
MainPage.Instance.DataContext = new NotificationItemViewModel();
```

Now I'd like to hear your ideas about this kind of passing data between classes in a Silverlight application. Do you have any idea?

**PS**: actually I answered my original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665798/how-to-access-usercontrols-datacontext-from-another-usercontrol) on Stackoverflow. But I'd like to hear your ideas in terms of code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I understood from your question here are my 5ct.

The `MainPage` class is the parent class of the `LoginClass`.

- **Parents should talk to children by using methods.**
- **Children should talk to parents by using events.**

So you should raise an event from the `LoginClass` to be consumed by the `MainPage` instead of accessing a property of the `MainPage`.

In this way you can easily test the code of the `LoginForm` independently of the `MainPage` whereas in you current implementation a `MainPage` always needs to be created before the `LoginOperation_Completed()` method can be used.

In addition in its current state your implementation has side effects because each time you create a new `MainPage` the `Instance` property will be changed.